# Should donating on behalf of an organization create a soft credit?

Tags: civicontribute, soft-credit

For online donations with the "on behalf of an organization" option enabled ... when someone opts for that, should that not create a soft credit for the individual submitting the form? I see an "Employee of" relationship gets added to that person (great), but no soft credit. Is that by design or a bug? (It would make sense to me if a soft credit was created.)

(We're on CiviCRM 5.43.0 w/ Joomla 3.10.3.)